# using jquery ui modal dialog to submit a form

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I am having difficulty using JQuery UI Modal Dialog when submitting a form. The intent is you hit the submit button, the modal pop ups and depending on your selection from the modal the form either submits or it doesn't. Instead the modal pops up and automatically submits

Front end:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Please double check to be sure all data is entered correctly.</p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save for later" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
        ValidationGroup="GroupSave" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return checkSubmit()" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
```

What I have tried for the jquery/js

A.)

```
function checkSubmit() {
$("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true,
    buttons: { "Submit": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); return true; },
        "Go Back": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); return false; }
    }
});
}
```

B.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { "Submit": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); return true; },
        "Go Back": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); return false; } 
    }
});
});

function checkSubmit() {
 $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

I understand how B (specifically the `checkSubmit`) fails, all it is doing is opening the dialog but for A I thought it would work considering I am having the buttons return values but that too is essentially *just* opening dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a button labeled "Submit" to open the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Please double check to be sure all data is entered correctly.</p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save for later" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="GroupSave" />
    <input type="button" id="preSubmit" value="Submit" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="ui-helper-hidden" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
```

Use the `Submit` button in the dialog to trigger the click event for your `<asp:Button>`.

```
function submitForm() {
    $('input#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
}
function checkSubmit() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        "modal": true,
        "buttons": {
            "Submit": function() {
                submitForm();
            },
            "Go Back": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#preSubmit').click(function(e) {
        checkSubmit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $('button#saveForLater').click(function(e) {
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: the "Go Back" works without a hitch but hitting Submit in the dialog does nothing but close the dialog, the page doesn't submit

Comment: @peroija: (Sorry!) The `checkSubmit` function should set the `ret` variable to be returned. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: tried it with your changes and tried something else, no beans. firebug reveals that the check submit is returning undefined, not true or false.

Comment: @peroija: Sorry, should have realized the dialog button function were asynchronous. Updated answer. Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rWjXU/ (fiddle is proof-of-concept as fiddle doesn't support asp.net :) )

Comment: now we've gotten somewhere. just a couple corrections to your code for future users. for `$('button#saveForLater').click(function(e)` drop the last two lines (`e.preventDefault();` and `return false;`) and change the `'button#'` to `'input#'`. thanks for the all the help