# modal prompt - how to rewrite this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have the following javascript confirm dialog, and I would like to make it modal, so I can style it, accordingly to my page design. Dialog works as it is, I just want to make it modal, using plain javascript or jquery, but without using jquery user interface.

Here is my code:

```
$(".oneUser").submit(function() {    
    var agree=confirm("Record will be deleted! \n Are you sure?");
    if (agree)
        return true ;
    else
        return false ;       
});
```

Regards,Zoran

Comment: http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/ the CSS is pretty easy to edit.

Comment: Prompts are built-in synchronous stuff, so yeah, you'll have to make some hidden absolute/fixed divs or generate them on the fly and bind callbacks to their yes/no buttons, or use an already existing plugin.

Comment: You are better off, using a specialized plugin: I can recommend Impromptu - a jQuery plugin. http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: You can use jQuery UI Dialog plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation. It's not possible to style the javascript confirm dialog.

Comment: This has been deprecated and is no longer being supported is the message displayed on apprise site :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same structure found in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743751/jquery-modal-dialog-box-isnt-submitting-my-form/12380436#12380436) and apply it here.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="confirm" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showConfirmDialog(message) {
    $("#confirm").html(message);
    $("#confirm").dialog('open');
}

$(function() {
    var submitForm = $('.oneUser');
    var submit = false;

    $("#confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Submit': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                submit = true;
                submitForm.submit();
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#confirm").parent().appendTo($(".oneUser")); 

    submitForm.submit(function() {
        if (submit) {
            return true;
        } else {
            showConfirmDialog("Record will be deleted! <BR /> Are you sure?");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```