# jQuery Dialog Form submit not advancing

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Using this solution as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743751/jquery-modal-dialog-box-isnt-submitting-my-form).  I am successfully opening a jQuery Dialog but cannot get the page to advance to the next form on post.  You can see where I changed the submit method to the form with no luck.

jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(function(){

            // jQuery UI Dialog    

            $('#jq-dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes, I saved the document.": function() {
                        //document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
                        $('#testconfirmJQ').submit();
                    },
                    "No, I forgot.  Cancel.": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('form#testconfirmJQ').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("span#dialog-email strong").html($("input#emailJQ").val());
                $('#jq-dialog').dialog('open');
            });          

        });
```

Form tag:

```
<form action="tech_maintenance_multiple.php" method="post" id="testconfirmJQ" name="testconfirmJQ">
```

Submit Button:

```
    <input type="submit" id="submitJQ" name="submitJQ" value="Please save this form and click here to add another AC" />
      </form>
<div id="jq-dialog" title="REMINDER!">
    <p class="alert alert-error">You must save this document and attach it later to an email when all systems are complete.  Did you save it?
</div>
```

Comment: When I reproduce your content, the page advances when I click the button. I think your code is good. Maybe you're experiencing something as simple as caching on your browser.

Comment: Really?  I tried IE and Chrome with no luck...I can't figure it out...

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Can you please check the console tab of Firebug in Firefox whether there are any errors or not. Also put debugger inside the dialog yes button function and form submit event o check if execution hits them or not.